# Decomposition in modular representation theory

Tags: representation-theory

Let $C_3=\{1,x,x^2\}$ and $V=\mathbb{F}_{11}^2$. Now the action of $x$ on $V$ is represented by the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
7 & 2 \\
10 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
and thus the action of $x^2$ has matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 9 \\
1 & 7
\end{pmatrix}
Since both characteristic polynomials have no roots over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ can I conclude that this representation is irreducible?

Comment: I don't get the downvote..

Comment: Ignore it. I just undid it. It is probably [this account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9003/amwhy) that just reactivated from a year ban for irregular voting, and now it is back to doing the same.

Comment: I get for $x^2$ the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}3&3\\4&7\end{pmatrix}$ with eigenvalues $8\cdot 8=64=9$ and $10\cdot 10=100=1$. But regardless of $x^2$, if you take $v$ an eigenvector of $x$ for the eigenvalue $8$. Then $\mathbb{F}_{11}v$ is a proper invariant subspace of $x$, therefore closed under the action of $x$.

Comment: @OscarRascal thanks to you comment I noticed that my first matrix was wrong. In fact also the matrix doesn't have eigenvalues. Question edited.

Comment: Note that if $V\subset\mathbb{F}_{11}^2$ is a proper subspace that is invariant for $x$, then it must be a one-dimensional subspace of eigenvectors. If you find that $x$ doesn't have eigenvalues in the field, then there cannot be any such $V$.

Comment: @OscarRascal you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I prefer the comments, it annoys more those who serially vote to close questions and down-vote them. For all it matters the question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, you may conclude that the representation is irreducible.  Were it to have a $C_3$ invariant subspace, it would have to be one dimensional but that exactly means it would be spanned by an eigenvector.

In fact, $C_3$ has no non-trivial one dimensional representations over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ -- this is just because $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ has no third roots of unity. Moreover this representation you wrote down is the unique non-trivial irreducible representation of $C_3$ over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the fact about roots of unity? I'm quite new to representation theory

Comment: Well an $n$th root of unity in a field is an element $x$ such that $x^n =1$.   If $C_n$ were to act linearly on an $1$ dimensional vector space, then a generator for $C_n$ must act by multiplying by an $n$th root of unity.   $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ has no third roots of unity other than 1 itself (In general $\mathbb{F}_p$ has non-trivial $3$rd roots of unity iff $p \equiv 1$  mod 3), but if a generator of $C_3$ were to act by $1$ then the whole representation must be the trivial representation.